# how to write an recursive function in python based on usecase

Tags: python, recursion

I've an endpoint which returns *next_cursor* and *data* as response by passing *current_cursor* as query param in the endpoint.

Now how I can use the *next_cursor* as *current_cursor* and pass it within the same endpoint till it doesn't return the *next_cursor* value.

```
current_cursor = x

def fetch_data(cursor):
     response = "example.com?{cursor}".format(cursor=cursor))
     response = response.text
     data = json.loads(response)
     /* make some operations with the data */
     next_cursor = data['next_cursor']
     return next_cursor
```

Comment: Ideally the data entity itself should be iterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is recursion basics:

```py
def fetch_data(cursor):
    # previous stuff

    if 'next_cursor' in data:
        next_cursor = data['next_cursor']
        return fetch_data(next_cursor)  # recurse
    else:  # stop recursing
        return data  # or whatever else you want


final_data = fetch_data(current_cursor)
```